# Having troubles converting pandas datetime to unix time stamp

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, unix-timestamp, string-to-datetime

What I need to do is convert 'year-month-day' timestamp to Unix time stamp do somethings with it then change it back to date time series. I am working with '1999-09-07' as my timestamp. I am getting an error : invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1999-09-07'

```
df1['timestamp'] = df1['timestamp'].astype(np.int64) // 10**9
#Got back this 
ERROR:invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1999-09-07'


df1 = pd.read_csv('stock_CSV/' + ticker + '.csv')
pd.to_datetime(df1['timestamp'],unit='ns', origin='unix')
df1['timestamp'] = df1['timestamp'].astype(np.int64) // 10**9
#
#....some code
#
pd.to_datetime(df1['timestamp'], unit='s')
```

What I am expecting is a my dates converted to unix timestamp then converted back

Comment: Your timestamp looks like string. Try `df1['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['timestamp'])` first.

Comment: I tried that but I was still getting the same error

Comment: Please make a [mcve]

Comment: `df1['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['timestamp']).astype...`

Comment: I don't think I can minimalize it even more than what I have here. import the data, convert to datetime then try to convert it to unix timestamp, then convert it back

Comment: Thank you Quang Hoang I had to while importing it to set index and parse dates then use what you have here to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Calling `astype('int64')` on a Timestamp Series return the number of *seconds* even though the Timestamps may have a resolution of nanosecond.

You can do it the old way, by counting the seconds from Jan 1, 1970 to the timestamps:

```
# random epoch times, in nanoseconds
t = np.random.randint(1e9 * 1e9, 2e9 * 1e9, 10)

# convert to Timestamps
dates = pd.to_datetime(t, unit='ns')

# convert back to nanoseconds
epoch = (dates - pd.Timestamp('1970-01-01')).total_seconds() * 1e9

# verify that we did the conversion correctly
assert np.isclose(t, epoch).all()
```

Comment: I am not sure with what you have here to put it together for my data. You have random times as t then converting them to date-time then subtracting Jan, 1 1970, maybe would I or how would I convert my timestamps from 'year-month-day' to seconds?

Comment: The Unix timestamp is simply the number of seconds since midnight on Jan 1, 1970. To get the nanoseconds, you multiply that by 1e9